# How to Intall Windows 7 along with windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, partitioning, efi

why installing windows 7 along with windows 10 is such a mess last time i did it i ended up with complete data loss .
How can i install windows 7 pro 64 bit in uefi secure boot enabled cuz every time i m in uefi mode windows 7 installer is not detecting. 
if i somehow enters in installer there error say cant install in this partition cuz its gpt .
i dont want to format or change anything in my hdd .
and

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a Virtual Machine? I would use Windows 10 as host and create a virtual machine with Windows 7, either through Hyper-V or Oracle VM, depending on what you need in features.

Comment: Step 1 install Windows 7 in UEFI mode. Step 2 install Windows 10.  Windows 7 64-bit supports UEFI/GPT if the installation doesn’t detect your GOT HDD the you are doing something wrong